# Using @classmethod for creating objects in django for testing purposes

Tags: python, django

Both on the higher level perspective work, however which is preferred method for creating objects for testing and why ?

Clarification: For testing purposes, that is , for testing the `model` created in the `test_models.py` file

**First Way:**

Using @classmethods

```
class AuthorModelTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Author.objects.create(first_name="Big", last_name="Bob")
```

**Second Way:**

Or passing `self` instead of referring to the `class`

```
class AuthorModelTest(TestCase):
    def setUpTestData(self):
        Author.objects.create(first_name="Big", last_name="Bob")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined as classmethod in `TestCase` so you should do the same in your code. Maybe both versions work right now but in the future releases of Django it can break the compatibility of your code with Django. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData).

> **classmethod TestCase.setUpTestData():**
>   The class-level atomic block described above allows the creation of
>   initial data at the class level, once for the whole TestCase.

Just follow the example from docs:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Set up data for the whole TestCase
        cls.foo = Foo.objects.create(bar="Test")
        ...
```